# Matlab Taylor series

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, matlab

In matlab, given a function $f(x)$ let's say $f(x)=e^{2x}$

If we know $\int _0^a\:f(x)=0.4$ how can we calculate $a$ with a precision of three decimals.

I integrated the Taylor series of $f(x)$ in the interval $0,a$ made that a function $h(a)$ and solved the equation $h(a)-0.4=0$. By changing $n$ in the series (number of terms added together) $a$ will vary of course, but how do I make it so that it has a precision of three decimals

Comment: Just to check, $f(x)$ changes, yeah? It's not always an exponential?

Comment: Can you find the indefinite integral $F(x) = \int f(x)dx + C$?  If so, You can solve for $a$ via $F(a)-F(0) = 0.4$.

Comment: No, f(x) doesn't change.

Comment: I'm not looking for the exact value of $a$. Thank you though